# Is it possible to style StaticImage with styled-components in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, styled-components, gatsby-image

I try to style StaticImage in Gatsby with styled-components this way:

```
    const HeroImage = styled(StaticImage)`
        display: block;
        grid-row: 1/1;
        grid-column: 7/-1;
    `;
```

and render it like this:

```
    <HeroImage
      src="../assets/images/hero.svg"
      alt="portfolio"
      placeholder="blurred"
    />
```

I don't know why, but if this component is styled it doesn't show up. Is it possible to use styled-components to style StaticImage in Gatsby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to use styled-components to style StaticImage in
> Gatsby?

No, is not possible. It's a known restriction that relies in the fact that `StaticImage` doesn't support HOC (**H**igh-**O**rder **C**omponents) like `styled(StaticImage)` is.

From the [documentation](http://%20https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#using-staticimage-with-css-in-js-libraries):

> The StaticImage component does not support higher-order components,
> which includes the `styled` function from libraries such as Emotion
> and styled-components. The parser relies on being able to identify
> `StaticImage` components in the source, and passing them to a function
> means this is not possible.